# Java Future.get() doesn't return

Tags: java, multithreading, disruptor-pattern

From the code below or [ValueMutationEventHandler](https://github.com/lydonchandra/disruptor/blob/master/src/test/com/lmax/disruptor/support/ValueMutationEventHandlerTest.java), why can't I do future2.get(), wait for future2 to complete and then get the results ?

If I do future2.get(), it'll wait forever.

```
    import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
    import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.Future;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

    import junit.framework.Assert;

    import org.junit.Test;

    import com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor;
    import com.lmax.disruptor.ClaimStrategy;
    import com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer;
    import com.lmax.disruptor.WaitStrategy;

    int numPublisher = 1;
    int numConsumer = 1;
    int parties = numPublisher + numConsumer;
    CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(parties);

    RingBuffer<ValueEvent> ringBuffer = new RingBuffer<ValueEvent>(
            ValueEvent.EVENT_FACTORY, 8192,
            ClaimStrategy.Option.MULTI_THREADED,
            WaitStrategy.Option.YIELDING
    );

    int iteration = 10;
    ValuePublisher valuePublisher = new ValuePublisher(
            barrier, ringBuffer, iteration
    );

    ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    Future future = execService.submit(valuePublisher);

    ValueMutationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValueMutationEventHandler(Operation.ADDITION);

    BatchEventProcessor<ValueEvent> eventProcessor = new BatchEventProcessor<ValueEvent>(ringBuffer, 
            ringBuffer.newDependencyBarrier(),
            eventHandler
    );

    barrier.await();
    Future future2 = execService.submit(eventProcessor);

    //////////////////////////////
    // Why do I need sleep here? Why doesn't future2.get works?
    /////////////////////////////
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    Assert.assertEquals(eventHandler.getValue(), 45L );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`  in order not to wait a long time and timeout the the operation.

Use above instead of `Thread.sleep(1000);` , you don't need `Thread.sleep(int)`

If Future.get does not return sth you may need to check `BatchEventProcessor` to see whats going on in there. If it does not return anthing Future.get can't return anything as well. Place a debug point into `BatchEventProcessor` to make sure it really returns a result in the expected time frame you require.